# How do I properly update my table using ajax asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have this table which I've structured like this

```
<table id="foo-filtering" class="table table-bordered table-hover toggle-circle" data-page-size="7">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <partial name="_Item" />
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <div class="ft-right">
                    <ul class="pagination"></ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And here is the partial view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">

                <div class="container-1">
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="@item.ProductImage" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="body">
                        <h3>@item.ItemName</h3>
                        <p>@item.SubTitle</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box-button">
                        <p>@item.SKU</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box-button">
                        <p class="mt-3 mr-2">$@item.Price</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Export</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </nav>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And the way I'm retreiving the items is by checking the database for the items that belongs to that user.. Note that I'm returning null there, that's important.

```
public IActionResult ReturnItems()
{
    Items = new List<EbayProduct>();
    using (var ctx = new UserContext())
    {
        Items = ctx.Users.Include(x => x.Items).Where(x => x.Username == "Admin").FirstOrDefault().Items;
    }

    //return PartialView("_Item", Items);
    return null;
}
```

And I have this piece of JavaScript that updates the partial view once every .5 seconds, just so that if I delete an item it will then update the view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(CheckAvailability, 500);
    });

    function CheckAvailability() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Dashboard/CheckChange",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            mimeType: "text/html",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    $('.items').load("/Dashboard/ReturnItems");
                    console.log("Updated!");

                }
                else {
                    console.log("Failed!");
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Here is the issue..
Right now it works great, the table looks the way it's suppose to, you can shuffle through the pagenation without any issues.. However! If I were to delete something from the database, it won't update the partial view. Even if I change `return null;` to `return PartialView("_Item", Items);`

I believe that's because I didn't add the css class `items` to the table, but if I do that, the table won't look normal, it will just display all the items in one line without any pagenation etc.

Comment: 500 is half a second. I recommend you instead use setTimeout in the success method

Comment: I've never heard of that, is that a JS function?

Comment: Seems you are using some plugin script to manage pagination. Will probably need to work with API of that plugin when you modify the table yourself. Not enough known about how your pagination works